# Open bracket doesn't work in Internet Explorer DevTools

Tags: internet-explorer, css-selectors, internet-explorer-11

Trying to select elements in Internet Explorer 11 "Dev Tools". I cannot open the bracket ("[").

I tried to write it in Chrome and Firefox and in different text editors and it works fine.

I also tried with another keyboard - no luck.

Is this a known IE issue? Google search didn't return anything peculiar.

If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: I do not understand properly, can you please explain with more details or with the snapshot of the issue that how you are trying to open '[' bracket while selecting the elements from developer tools in IE 11? It can help us to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Pressing the "[" key (AltGr+F in my case) on the keyboard does nothing.

Comment: I check for those shortcut keys to switch the tabs in developer tools and I find that it is not working in IE and MS Edge. I will try to provide feedback to Microsoft developers regarding this issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: They're not talking about keyboard shortcuts, they're talking about typing the "[" character in the F12 search bar. I'm not seeing this issue on my machine.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT That is correct. I tried this on multiple machines. However, it happens only when using the Croatian-keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a painful issue in IE but since it's not developed anymore, there is no hope for a fix. You can work around it by:

- Using another browser for development
- If you can't use it because of some reason (like your company doesn't allow it), you can copy-paste the symbol from a text editor (or maybe it can be faster if you call the window element in the dev console and copy that one).

Comment: I am working around it... Using Chrome for development and IE for production.